# Authentication token gets invalidated unexpectedly when developing on different machines - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure, asp.net-identity

I have a web application that is using ASP.NET Identity 2.1.0, and have all authorization tokens set to expire after 365 days. I recently started working with one other developer, and the entire project has been in source control since the beginning (for about a year). When we added the 2nd developer a few weeks ago, and he tried publishing the code to Microsoft Azure from his machine, it invalidated all tokens that had already existed, forcing everyone who uses the software to login again. We could not figure out what could have caused it, but now it happened again locally on his machine (without publishing to Azure). Does anyone know what could be causing this to happen?

Here is the code that sets the token expiration in Startup.Auth.cs

```
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

**Edit:** We are using Code First, and the problem occurred yesterday when he rolled back his local database to a target migration, then deleted the migration he did not want, then pulled a migration from source control that I created on a separate branch, then he ran it. Then when he ran the project, the tokens were invalidated.

Comment: does the new machine use the same key to encrypt and decrypt authnetication token?

Comment: I'm sorry, where would I find that?

Comment: I don't think that would be the issue, though, because it only happened twice in the last two weeks, and we were successful many times in between. I also just edited my post to mention that we are using Code First migrations in case that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Do you have machine key specified in your `web.config`?

Comment: I do not have machine key specified